# Linux TTY S1 open failed

Tags: linux, file-io, crash, tty

When I open, read or write to my embedded Linux TTY S1, my OS crashes. The crash logs are as follows:

```
[<80105990>] dump_stack+0x8/0x34 
[<8010b1d8>] sb2_intr+0x5c/0x88
[<80177adc>] handle_IRQ_event+0x78/0x170
[<8017a0e4>] handle_percpu_irq+0x5c/0xbc
[<80123c40>] do_IRQ+0xc8/0x16c
[<80101800>] ret_from_irq+0x0/0x4
[<80307164>] serial8250_handle_port+0x320/0x374
[<8030723c>] serial8250_interrupt+0x84/0x1dc
[<80177adc>] handle_IRQ_event+0x78/0x170
[<8017a0e4>] handle_percpu_irq+0x5c/0xbc
```

dmesg logs says:

```
serial8250: too much work for irq3
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the error it looks like some IRDA device problem/isa serial or a bug mentioned on http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2009-04/msg45760.html and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=986761.